# Why does setup.py sometimes include 'post' in the generated package name?

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I routinely build packages with the command `python setup.py sdist`.  Sometimes the resulting package contains the suffix 'post' and sometimes it does not.  Here's an example

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 sectools users 5936 Jul  6 18:30 update_sos_inv-3.0.0-20230706.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 sectools users 6077 Jul  6 19:42 update_sos_inv-3.0.0.post20230706.tar.gz
```

This phenomena is exacerbated by the fact that pip seems to prefer the non-post variety, so the file I pushed to my server last had a necessary fix, but pip insisted on installing the older, broken package.

This has bugged me for years, and I've never seen an explanation for this behavior.  I'm sure someone will point me right to the section in the documentation that explains it and I'll feel like an idiot, but at least then I'll know :)

Comment: What are the contents of the build script?